# How to use if statements in verilog

Tags: if-statement, verilog

I'm a total disaster at using verilog for implementing but this issue is walking on my nerves around an hour and I can't fix it!

here's my code

```bash
genvar i;
assign eq=1; 
assign gr=0;
generate for(i=7 ; i>=0 ; i=i-1)
        initial begin
        if(eq&&~gr)
            if (a[i]&~b[i])
              initial begin
               assign gr=1;
               assign eq=0;
              end
            else if (~a[i]|b[i])
            initial begin
              assign gr=0;

    assign eq=0;
    end
    end
endgenerate
```

the idea was to create some if statements so I could compare a[i] and b[i] if gr was 0 and eq was 1. 
the algorithm cannot be changed cause it's an assignment and I have to work this way but I'm really eager to find where the problem is (verilog's error description is not helping at all)

Comment: Verilog's error description may help

Comment: You cannot nest two initial blocks into each other. Get rid of the second initial keyword and just leave begin/end block.

Answer (score 1):

- `generate` blocks are used to replicate hardware at compile/elaboration time
- `initial` blocks only run one at time 0. Changes to `a` and `b` will have no effect. It is illegal to nest `initial` blocks.
- `assign` statements should not be used in `initial` blocks (it is legal but highly discouraged and is in consideration for depreciation). Generally a non-tri-state `assign` to a net should be done only once.
- For continuous evaluation you need to use an `always` block

Best guess, this is the functionality you intended:

```
integer i;
reg eq,gr; 

always @* begin
  for (i=7 ; i>=0 ; i=i-1) begin
    if (eq&&~gr) begin
      if (a[i]&~b[i]) begin
        gr=1;
        eq=0;
      end
      else if (~a[i]|b[i]) begin
        gr=0;
      end
    end
    eq=0;
  end
end
```

Comment: hello and thanks for your amazing response! but I have a question here!
I have faced these error and i don't know what to do!
"LHS in procedural continuous assignment may not be a net: gr."

Comment: Means that you cannot assign a value to a variable defined as a wire, inside an always block. It has to be defined as a reg.

Comment: how can i change the registers stored data? how can i give it a new number? I could not do that with "assign".